# Read file using Python while preserving text format

Tags: python, text, readfile

I am trying to read file without modifying the text format and then store it in variable so that I can perform Regex on it. I tried the following code

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
```

And it stores text like this: [first_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qki1M.png)

But I want to store text in a variable *data* like this: [required_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Owf.png)

How can I achieve this, I search for many tutorials, blogs but couldn't find the exact solution.

Comment: Try `print(data)`.

Comment: Note that the data *is stored* as is. See all those newline characters, `\n`? Those are the line breaks in your required_output. The required_output is just a *rendering* of the data, not the actual data.

Comment: You're confusing the _representation_ of the string with the _content_  of the string. The variable contains exactly the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Note that line breaks/starting a new line is stored by python/programs as `\n`.

Perhaps consider using `.replace('\n', something)` to replace the 'newline' characters or `string.split('\n')` to split the entire document into a list of lines?

If you don't care about the lines and just want to retain the raw text, just replace them with whitespace characters by using `.replace('\n', ' ')`.